# I wanted to report if in case my application loads and hangs forever in any particular instance

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

There are some instances where application hangs and loads forever. How do i identify this and report using reporter event. I am stuck with this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at creating recovery scenarios for the situation

Comment: I could use recovery scenario. but problem is app page shows "loading" and it is the right way to act for app. For example, it might be to "search a patient". So it shows "loading".. but i just need to report it this "loading" shows for more than sometime.. say 3 minutes. Which means the app is actually stuck and hung  and is not going to work for sure..

Comment: Then use a recovery scenario that reports a fail after a given time has elapsed.  You can't use "forever" as that never ends though...

Comment: How do i do that? Can we use recovery scenario that reports after a given time? can u pls help me with that. what is the option available for the same in recovery scenario?

Comment: Easy, wait for an infinite amount of time and fail the test if the application is still stuck (further reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).